..set a time for
We use the phrase, "set a time for," typically, with an event. Set a time for carousing. Set a time for snuggling. Set a time for a phone call, etc. And that makes sense.
But we also use it with the time the event is to occur. For example,

Want to snuggle?
Sure, let's set a time for next month.

And that doesn't make sense.
I can see "set a time during next month" or "set a time in next month," but not for next month. Is that usage improper? Is there a proper prep or...?

'Set a time for' + [actual time] is idiomatic with a limited number of time expressions. The 'actual time' expression may be fairly hazy ('sometime next year'; 'late September') but refers to an actual specified time (point or larger) rather than just an interval (*'set a time for a week/fortnight/month...'). It usually includes 'next'.

Related: Schedule on Tuesday.

"To set a time" or "to set a date" are very similar, but only the latter is found in M-W's dictionary.
According to Merriam-Webster's dictionary, "for"  is correct in that context when the complement of the preposition represents the happening.

(Merriam-Webster)
set a date idiom
: to decide on a day (for some event to take place or to begin)
They have not yet set a date for the trial.

This is verified by the two Google searches concerning these idioms.
set a time for, set a date for
Nevertheless, if we examine the first example in that dictionary, we can see that it is possible for the complement to represent  a period in time in which the date will be chosen.

M-W  Recent Examples on the Web
Prosecutors have pressed the judge to set a date for this summer.
— Compiled By Democrat-Gazette Staff From Wire Reports, arkansasonline.com, 15 Mar. 2024

This is not consistent from the point of view of what "for" can mean. The closest meaning in OLD is not proper.

for used to show that something is arranged or intended to happen at a particular time

an appointment for May 12
We're invited for 7.30.


There is no such definiton of "for" in M-W's dictionary.
"During" and "in" are not themselves too precise: maybe what could be understood when using is that  the setting of the time will occur in the mentioned month. What is really involved is a complex preposition such as "to be not earlier nor later than".

Sure, let's set a time to be not earlier nor later than next month.

However, if such a precision of wording suits well administrative formalism, it is not in almost all cases what is needed for colloquial speech. There appears to be no exact preposition and I guess this usage of "for" could be another case of usage in the making, which would sometime in the future be the occasion for adding a definition to the already numerous ones in the dictionaries (24 of them in the SOED).
In the more detailed SOED (The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary), there is a definition that might match the intended meaning, but I will mention it as a mere point to consider, this being so in reason of the fact that it is possible that "destination" does not include periods of time.

(SOED) for IV Of purpose, result or destination.
12 To be received by, to belong to; to be used by, with, or in connection with.


Sure, let's set a time "to belong to" next month. (Not idiomatic, merely  intended to suggest actual sense)


Cambridge gives for for: "on the occasion of or at the time of". Example: "I'd like an appointment with the doctor for some time this week." This is certainly close to the OP's example. Although the OP's example is a little humorous so it's hard to judge its probability.

two Google searches, not researches. He researches his answers before posting. He searches for clues on the internet. He does internet searches using Google.

@StuartF The definition you are referring to does not say  "particular time in a time range": the particular time (time, date) is in the range "next month". The preposition "at" is obviously not the preposition needed; the op mentions "during" and "in", not "at". "On the occasion of next month"? "set the time at the time of next month"?  "some time this week" is a point in time within the week, just as the date is a point in time within the next month.
